# iOS: In UITableview Programmatically Created button repeats Twice?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My project is based on parsing XML data and displaying screen, In my project I need to set UIButton programaitcally inside a table view cell. I done it but when I run it the button repeats twice. Like this
[image]

I dont know to solve this Here is the code i tried

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0)
        return  [eventarray count];
    if (section == 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"eventCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        Eventlist *msglist = [eventarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = msglist.invitationdet;
        NSLog(@"Array %@",[SingleTonClass sinlgeTon].colorArray);
        NSInteger stat=msglist.readflag;
        if([[SingleTonClass sinlgeTon].colorArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] || stat == 1 ) {
            NSInteger stat1 = msglist.responseflag;
            if(stat1 == 1){
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            }
            else {
             cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            }
        }
               else{
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

          }
    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        UIButton *viewmoreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        viewmoreButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 80.0f, 30.0f);
        [viewmoreButton setTitle:@"View More" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
        [cell addSubview:viewmoreButton];
        [viewmoreButton addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(viewMore:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.backgroundColor = [ UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The button has to show only on second cell, Please help me how to solve this Thanks in Advance

Comment: i have updated my answer take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace [cell addSubview:viewmoreButton]; with [cell.contentView addSubview:viewmoreButton];

In Detail

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
    Eventlist *msglist = [eventarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
      cell.textLabel.text = msglist.invitationdet;   
      NSLog(@"Array %@",[SingleTonClass sinlgeTon].colorArray);
      NSInteger stat=msglist.readflag;
      if([[SingleTonClass sinlgeTon].colorArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] || stat == 1 ) {
        NSInteger stat1 = msglist.responseflag;
        if(stat1 == 1){
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        }
        else {
         cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
    }
           else{
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

      if (indexPath.section==1) {
            UIButton *viewmoreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            viewmoreButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 80.0f, 30.0f);
            [viewmoreButton setTitle:@"View More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:viewmoreButton];
            cell.textLabel.text =alphaArray[indexPath.row];
      }

      return cell;
}
```

Comment: And that would stop tableview from reusing the cells and showing up the button in each cell?

Comment: @Zen that is what he need in section 1 he needs buttons on cells. and my answer works for that requirement.

Comment: If you see his code and the ss, he is getting the button in cells of both sections. His problem is that he doesn't want that to happen in 0th section because he is simply not adding it there, still sees it. Thats what tableview reusing the cells don't you think?

Comment: @Zen please take a look at my answer i have written the code in detail for you if my answer is wrong let me know

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you're adding the button to the `UITableViewCell`, and then when `reloadData` is called on the table, the cell is queued for reuse with that button still attached.

Create your own `UITableViewCell` subclass and use that for the section of your table that will require a custom button.

Comment: This seems reasonable! You need two different kinds of `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 1):

Might causing due to the **Reusability** of the Cell, So initialise the UITableViewCell within the sections block

Try this :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"eventCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell ;

if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        Eventlist *msglist = [eventarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = msglist.invitationdet;
       // .... . ...
          }
 if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIButton *viewmoreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        // ........
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: its not working when i try this if(indexPath.section == 0) is not even visible only cell with if(indexPath.section == 1) was visible, when i apply breakpoint if(indexPath.section == 0) not even getting called

Comment: Then error might be with your dataSource . Check this Value **[eventarray count]**

Comment: Kumar Ki is absolutely right about reusability of cells. You need a different identifier for each 'type' of cell. Add code for `if (cell == nil)` and initialize your elements in it's block. Nick Galasso's solution is a step improved. Subclassing will inhibit you from making any mistakes.

Comment: If you still has the problem. I just give you the alternative : just go through with two UITableViewCell's  **static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"eventCell";
   static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"eventCell1";
 
if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; ...
}if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath]; ...
}**

Answer (score 1):

This is what expected to happen because the table view is reusing the cell with the identifier you mentioned. There are two ways to avoid this :

1) User two different prototype cells (if you are using Interface Builder which I think you are) with different identifiers and getting a reference for the cell according to the required  one.

2) If you don't want to change this approach of yours, it can also make the same thing happen but with slight modification. First of all, you are adding a button to the cell on every call of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method which is simply wrong. What you can do is check if the button already exist and if its not, only create it then.

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2000];
if(btn == nil){
  // Your button code here
  [btn setTag:2000];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
}
```

Now simply check if its the 0th section, get the button's reference and hide it, and if its 1st section, unhide it.